# Customize serialization to JSON to leave some fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a .NET Core API project backed by MongoDB.

I have a sample model class:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("aField")]
    public string AField { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("hiddenField")]
    public string HiddenField { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to achieve is to set the `HiddenField` to `null` every time when it is returned as the payload in my controller. I am thinking of a custom JSON serializer but don't know how to do it. Can anyone help?

NB: I don't want to manually set the `HiddenField` to `null` in every single controller or action.

Comment: public string HiddenField { get; set; } = null ; this line makes the Default value of  HiddenField equals to null

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada That did not change anything as `null` is already the default value for `string` type

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada After I get the value from the DB, this value is populated. When it is sent back to the client, I want it to be null.

Comment: @Antediluvian You should never mix up the infrastructure layer with the application layer -> do **not use** the `MyModel` class at the application layer

Comment: @Antediluvian now i get the Question , U can Create a new Dto Mapp every thing u want in it, its better than expose  the Base Entity.
create a Dto and while mapping, ignore the HiddenField or not mapp it at all

Comment: @SirRufo agree , So the Dto Comes for the Rescue.

Comment: @SirRufo Admittedly, the segragation of layers is a good design but it creates overhead on my small project.

Comment: @Antediluvian I would say it will give you some freedom. There are some fields I need only on the database layer (f.i. index of items, concurrency detection, ...) and it will make a hard time if I had to deal with them at the application layer. You should start your application at the application layer and build the persistence layer (database) at the very last part -> you will never ever have a feeling of overhead ;o)

Answer (score 2):

Apply [`JsonIgnore`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PropertyJsonIgnore.htm) attribute to `HiddenField` property.

```cs
public class MyModel
{
    // ... other members

    [JsonIgnore]
    [BsonElement("hiddenField")]
    public string HiddenField { get; set; }
}
```

Since under the hood ASP.Net Core uses [Newtonsoft.Json (aka Json.NET)](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library to de/serialize JSON payloads, you can control serialization and deserialization with the attributes from that library.

Note that `JsonIgnore` attribute works in both directions: if a client sends `hiddenField` to the server, the controller won't populate it in the model.

It also worth noting that starting with ASP.NET Core 3.0, Json.NET won't necessarily be the default mechanism of JSON serialization (see [this announcement](https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/90)): in the 3.x versions of ASP.NET Core, one must ensure that integration with Json.NET is plugged in, for current solution to work.

Regarding the architectural discussion in the OP comments, it all depends. Of course, mixing such attributes as `JsonIgnore` and `BsonElement` in one class means coupling of two separate concerns: service API and data persistence. However, in small and simple applications, proper separation of concerns might be an overkill, and the most straightforward approach might be a better fit.

Comment: He said the value returned so,[JsonIgnore] isn't the answer since as u said it ignores both ways Response And Request.

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada He said "the value is returned as the payload in my controller" which IMO means  JSON returned from the controller to the client. Therefore, my answer works.

Comment: If previous answer doesn’t fir for you , you can also make setter protected or private. Newtonsoft will not fill this property by default.

Comment: @felix-b thanks for your explanantion. i ended up with the `IgnoreDataMember` attribute which looks similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to create a ViewModel (I tend to use ViewModel as a definition of any model I expose, either by sending it to a server side presentation layer or any external resource REST/etc via JSON/XML/etc).

In this instance, I'd create:

```
public class MyModelVM
{
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public string AField { get; set; }
  public string HiddenField { get; }
}
```

`HiddenField` has no set, so it will always be null. Then set your serialization options and return your JSON.

```
var myModelVM = new MyModelVM(); // however you want to create/map the values

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myModelVM, 
  Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, 
  new JsonSerializerSettings { 
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include
  });
```

If you didn't map values to `MyModelVM`, then the resulting JSON would look like:

```
{
  "Id" : null,
  "AField" : null,
  "HiddenField" : null,
}
```

Comment: Does that mean I have to call that `SerializeObject()` everywhere I need the object?

Comment: That is one method need to *convert* a c# object to JSON.